# Android - Parsing large files using SAX parser

Tags: android

- I am trying to parse the xml data coming from webservice using SAX parser, when i try to parse the data(size:7.4MB) using URL, it works fine but when I copy the xml data from the URL and place the xml file(size:7.4MB) in the raw folder, the parsing fails.
- When the size of file placed in raw folder is reduced to 1.95MB, it works fine. I have tried shuffling the tags to check if there are any issues with the data, I haven't found any.It works fine as long as the size doesn't exceed 1.95MB. Is there any size limit while parsing the data from raw folder in android? if yes what is the limit? or How to parse the large files using SAX parser?

Any pointers will really help me. Thanks in advance for your time and any help offered.

Regards,
Ramesh

```
02-14 17:35:35.651: DEBUG/asset(11035): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (2138421 vs 2097152) 
02-14 17:35:35.651: WARN/dalvikvm(11035): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0) 
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13 
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): java.lang.AssertionError: java.io.IOException 
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:89)
```

code

```
try { 
    System.out.println("1"); 
    //Xml.parse((url.openConnection().getInputStream()), Encoding.UTF_8, datahandler); 
    Xml.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample), Encoding.UTF_8, datahandler); 
    System.out.println("2"); 
    //xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("sample.xml")));
}catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println("Ramesh"+"XML Parsing exception:"+e);
}
```

error

```
Android DEBUG/asset(11035): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (2138421 vs 2097152) 
WARN/dalvikvm(11035): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): java.lang.AssertionError: java.io.IOException 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:89) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): at com.infosys.gss.ui.Login$2$1.run(Login.java:431) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): Caused by: java.io.IOException
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the parsing fails"?

Comment: [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355909/parsing-very-large-xml-documents-and-a-bit-more-in-java)

Comment: Can you put your code how you are doing this

Comment: 02-14 17:35:35.651: DEBUG/asset(11035): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (2138421 vs 2097152)
02-14 17:35:35.651: WARN/dalvikvm(11035): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): java.lang.AssertionError: java.io.IOException
02-14 17:35:35.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035):     at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:89)

Comment: Hi Saurabh, here is code:try{
          System.out.println("1");
          //Xml.parse((url.openConnection().getInputStream()), Encoding.UTF_8, datahandler);
          
          Xml.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample), Encoding.UTF_8, datahandler);
          System.out.println("2");

          //xr.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("sample.xml"))); 
         }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Ramesh"+"XML Parsing exception:"+e);
         }

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: you anr not supposed to write here. oh dear oh dear.

Comment: @DKIT Android  DEBUG/asset(11035): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (2138421 vs 2097152)
WARN/dalvikvm(11035): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): java.lang.AssertionError: java.io.IOException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035):     at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:89)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035):     at com.infosys.gss.ui.Login$2$1.run(Login.java:431)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11035): Caused by: java.io.IOException

Comment: This is a heck I believe might work change your xml extension to mp3, jpeg or any media format

Comment: @Ramesh, I have updated your question with the info you provided in the comments.  In future, if you have code or stacktrace to add, please click the `edit` button under your question and add the information there, rather than adding it in a comment.  It is much easier to read code and errors when they are part of the original question.