# xml parsers does not read such a large file contents

Tags: java, mysql, xml, parsing, dom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="test">
    <table_data name="test">
    <row>
        <field name="field1">406</field>
        <field name="field2">a2</field>
        <field name="field3">16</field>
        <field name="field4"></field>
        <field name="field5" xsi:type="xs:hexBinary">
[get the content from http://122.183.130.242/file/hex.txt path because i cannot give such a large content to stackoverflow]

        </field>
        <field name="field6">16</field>
    </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

I am trying to parse and read the content from the above xml file.

I am using a DOM parser and I also tried StAX parser to parse the XML but I cannot parse such a large file.

How can I parse large XML files?

Comment: DOM is not a good option for such a large files. If SAX also failing only option you have I think will be increase memory.

Comment: ya, that is why am asking friend. what will be the better approach for this one.

Comment: what error are you getting when you try to parse?

Comment: am did not get any error. but file parsing is skipped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355909/parsing-very-large-xml-documents-and-a-bit-more-in-java

Comment: @Mohan, I don't think there is one except memory increase (or) reduce file size, because you tried StaX also (which is some what last option for large files).

Comment: "file parsing is skipped" says that the parser isn't the problem, something else in your code is. If it were truly a problem of the file being too big, you'd get an OutOfMemoryError. To get better answers, post your code.

Comment: The file you linked to is 64 kilobytes. This is, by no means, "too large" to parse with even DOM – which wouldn't really bloat a file with a structure this simple anyway. (Assuming a desktop Java and its default memory settings.) Your error is somewhere else.

Comment: yes, the problem is fixed after restarting my system. i don't know why the problem happen like this. thanks guys for spending your time with me.

Comment: @Mohan - since the problem went away, please delete this question; it won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SAX Parser method `.parse(InputStream stream, HandlerBase handler)`

For the handler, you use [DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html).

For the 'stream' parameter, do this:

```
BufferedReader stream=new BufferedReader( new FileReader(String filename));
```

...where "filename" is, you guessed it, the name of your file.
Now I expect you to know how to use the DefaultHandler. Basically you overwrite the methods you're interested in.
Try to tweak the buffer size of the BufferedReader, and i think you'll be happy with the result.

Comment: i have a question, does this SAX parser will allow to change and update the xml content?