# Using Xpath in java to extract a value from a large xml file

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to extract a single value from a large xml file (part of a much larger xml project that I'm working on)

So the xml structure is like this:

```
<m:Report>
    <m:Messages>
        <m:report_type>
            <m:Report_Data> (last value)
                <m:Data_Item> (must be specific type)
                <m:Value> (want this)

After this all tags close properly
```

So right xpath query looks something like this:

```
XPathExpression expr = x.compile("//m:Report/m:Messages/m:Report_type/m:Report_Data[m:Data_Iten='PRICE'][last()]/m:Value/text()") ;
```

I'm not having much luck with this query, where am I going wrong?

Comment: If that's a very large XML file, you'd better use a SAX parser , or a StAX parser. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355909

Comment: By very large I meant about 250kb  ~10k lines of xml.   Think Sax / StAX would still be necessary?

Comment: Are you correctly handling namespaces? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath/6392700#6392700

Comment: That is a really good question, and I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are simply errors in your query. `Report_type` should be `report_type` and `Data_Iten` should be `Data_Item`:

```
XPathExpression expr = x.compile("//m:Report/m:Messages/m:report_type/m:Report_Data[m:Data_Item='PRICE'][last()]/m:Value/text()");
```

Assuming that you have a `Data_Item` in your input data with `PRICE`, then this should get you the `<m:Value>`.

Comment: Or if those are typos in submitting the question, I would question the use of [last()]. It's not obviously wrong, but you haven't given enough information for us to know that it is right.